# How to access struct member?

Tags: c++, struct

I've struct that declared in header file, but couldn't access it's member from implementing .cc file:

---header file---

```
 struct MyFilter : public RTBKIT::FilterBaseT<AgeFilter>
 {
 static constexpr const char* name = "Age";
 unsigned priority() const { return 10; }//Priority::Age; }

 void filter(FilterState& state) const;
 private:
      IntervalFilter<int> f;
}
---cc file ---
void MyFilter::filter(FilterState& state) {
    state.narrowConfigs(f.filter(...);
}
```

It says:  error: f was not declared in this scope.

Thanks,
Ann

Comment: Is filter supposed to be member function? At the moment it seems like it's declared as a free function. Didn't you mean `MyFilter::filter`?

Comment: Is this an attempt for a recursive function?

Comment: Nop, it's MyFilter::filter, but compiler complains the variable f which I put in the header file.

Comment: Because f is static you need to define it in your cc file. So far all you have is a declaration in the header.

Comment: Sorry not following you :) If you could create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it will be far easier to help you.

Comment: Header declaration for function `filter` declares it as `const`. The definition in `.cc` file has no `const`. These functions are unrealted. Is this how it is in your code? Aside from that everything looks more or less fine. The error message you quoted is unrealistic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass`f` along with `state` in order for it to be used *locally* in your `filter()` or write it as follows:

`void YourClass::YourFunction() { .. }`

Comment: state was used to get info from it, but f was private in header, I moved it out in order to compile. @FirstStep

Comment: @AnnW. We are having problems understanding you. Could you please expand what you mean?

Comment: Yes, how to use variable f - put the private member f in the implementation class(.cc) file. @FirstStep

Comment: @AnnW. I still don't get you. What is your native language? And I imagine if `f` is a private member then you should be able to view it. Try `this->f.filter()`

Comment: @AnnW. Did you include your cpp file inside your header file?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all the hints, I actually forgot prefix before the function and const after.

Ann